# Save iframe content as .xps/.pdf format without user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, vbscript, printing-web-page

I would like to know whether it is possible to save iframe content as .xps/.pdf format without the user interaction or not.

Currently, my coding is able to skip print dialog box and select default printer. However, it couldn't bypass the **Save As** dialog box.

Do anyone has some advice to solve this issue?

Browser: IE 9 (Don't support HTML 5)

**Javascript :**

```
function PrintDoc() 
{
    var TestPrint = null;
    TestPrint = this.document.frames['iframecontent'];
    if(TestPrint) //verify the content isn't empty or null
      TestPrint.bypassprint();
}
```

**VBScript :**

```
Sub bypassprint()
    call WB.ExecWB(6, 2) //bypass printer dialog box
    call Wb.Dispose()
End Sub
```

**HTML :**

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Print" onclick="javascript:PrintDoc();" id="btnSubmit" class="Btn" />
```

Assume that I have an iframe tag with id ="iframecontent" and I wish to print the iframe content as .xps/.pdf format without the user interaction.

The above code is able to bypass the printer dialog box but not the **Save As** dialog box.

Any advice given would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Server-side solution:
First: get the HTML, then pass it to a component that can create a pdf from it and voila ;-)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/334862/HTML-to-PDF-in-VB-NET-or-CS-NET

Client-side solution:
this is a bit harder, the browser does not allow you to generate a pdf without user interaction. BUT: you can send the html document to an API (you create it) which in return send a url where you can download the generated pdf. The do window.open(downloadUrl) and the user downloads the pdf without further dialogs.

For creating a pdf from html see the server-side solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. From your answer, Can I conclude that it needs to download the generated .pdf file in order to bypass user interaction? How about if I wish to save to a specific targeted folder such as "C:\" ?

Answer (score 0):

Client-side solution: you can use jsPDF library https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

This is the easiest example you can read in the documentation:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
// We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
    return true;
    }
};

// All units are in the set measurement for the document
// This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
doc.fromHTML($('#render_me').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

Where 'render_me' will be the section you want to Export.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do alert of the jsPDF library. But I think it probably couldn't fully support the IE 9 since it is written in HTML 5.

Comment: I have to read more carefully. Then, you will need a server side solution. But, you can do withoud a full postback, using PageMethods

Comment: I've tried to pass the iframe content to **Server Side** and it's able to **Save As** .xps/.pdf without the user interaction. However, it couldn't render the HTML and the document will be printed with tags such as <div id="content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>